# Extracting sub features from inside a df cell?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, feature-extraction

I have a dataframe containing several features of form:

```
Id, Acol,                   Bcol,   Ccol,           Dcol,
1,  X:0232,Y:10332,Z:23891, E:1222, F:12912,G:1292, V:1281
2,  X:432,W:2932            R:2392, T:292,U:29203   Q:2392
3,  Y:29320,W:2392          R:2932, G:239,T:2392    Q:2391

...about 10,000 Id's
```

- where 1,2,3 are the Id's.
- Acol, Bcol, Ccol, and Dcol are the feature columns,
- X, Y, Z, W are sub-features of feature "Acol" and so on...

How can I extract the sub-features/features from this sort of dataframe?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you want say to access all values in Bcol, and you loaded the dataframe into a pandas df, then simply do df['Bcol']. Was that all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not specific where you wanted to end up with the data in this frame, so I will simply show how to break out the features and sub features into a format that can be pivoted into a form as needed:

#### Code:

Most important element is taking a feature column and breaking out the sub features.  That can be done like:

```
def get_sub_features(feature_col):
    # split on commas and then colons
    feature_df = feature_col.str.split(',').apply(
        lambda feature: pd.Series(
            dict([sub_feature.split(':') for sub_feature in feature]),
            name=feature_col.name), 1)

    # add a feature name column to use as an index
    feature_df['feature'] = feature_col.name

    # name the columns as sub-feature for later stacking
    feature_df.columns.names = ['sub-feature']

    # return dataframe with id/feature_name index
    new_index = [feature_df.index.name, 'feature']
    return feature_df.reset_index().set_index(new_index)
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    Id  Acol                    Bcol    Ccol            Dcol
    1   X:0232,Y:10332,Z:23891  E:1222  F:12912,G:1292  V:1281
    2   X:432,W:2932            R:2392  T:292,U:29203   Q:2392
    3   Y:29320,W:2392          R:2932  G:239,T:2392    Q:2391"""
                          ), header=1).set_index(['Id'])
print(df)

feature_cols = ['Acol', 'Bcol', 'Ccol', 'Dcol']
stacked = pd.concat(get_sub_features(df[f]).stack() for f in feature_cols)
print(stacked)
```

#### Results:

```
                      Acol    Bcol            Ccol    Dcol
Id                                                        
1   X:0232,Y:10332,Z:23891  E:1222  F:12912,G:1292  V:1281
2             X:432,W:2932  R:2392   T:292,U:29203  Q:2392
3           Y:29320,W:2392  R:2932    G:239,T:2392  Q:2391

Id  feature  sub-feature
1   Acol     X               0232
             Y              10332
             Z              23891
2   Acol     W               2932
             X                432
3   Acol     W               2392
             Y              29320
1   Bcol     E               1222
2   Bcol     R               2392
3   Bcol     R               2932
1   Ccol     F              12912
             G               1292
2   Ccol     T                292
             U              29203
3   Ccol     G                239
             T               2392
1   Dcol     V               1281
2   Dcol     Q               2392
3   Dcol     Q               2391
dtype: object
```

#### Accessing Data:

Some examples:

```
print(stacked.xs('T', level=2))
print(stacked.iloc[stacked.index.get_level_values('sub-feature') == 'T'])
```

Results:

```
               0
Id feature      
2  Ccol      292
3  Ccol     2392

                           0
Id feature sub-feature      
2  Ccol    T             292
3  Ccol    T            2392
```